# R: bipartie projection in igraph and RAM usage

Tags: r, igraph, ram, projection

I try to make bipartie.projection in R (igraph library). When i try to make projection on network bigger than 4mb, R process consume all my memory (and SWAP) then it is terminated. I have 15 GB of RAM. I try to load Wikipedia networks from konect and only this: http://konect.uni-koblenz.de/networks/edit-frwikinews is working. My load code is bellow:

```
library(igraph)
nodesSet1 = unique(as.integer(as.character(out$`%`)))
nodesSet2 = unique(as.integer(as.character(out$bip)))

g <- graph.empty()
g <- add.vertices(g,nv=length(nodesSet1),attr=list(name=paste0('A',nodesSet1),
                                                   type=rep(TRUE,length(nodesSet1))))
g <- add.vertices(g,nv=length(nodesSet2),attr=list(name=paste0('B',nodesSet2),
                                                   type=rep(FALSE,length(nodesSet2))))

edgeListVec <- as.vector(t(as.matrix(data.frame(S1=paste0('A',out$`%`),
                             S2=paste0('B',out$bip)))))

g <- add.edges(g,edgeListVec)
kk <- bipartite_projection(g)
```

Do i do something wrong ? If not, how can i calculate required memory usage ? Or maybe i should calculate this in another way ? 
Thanks for help.